# Keeping only one unique column from data import using dplyr

Tags: r, select, dataframe, duplicates, dplyr

I'm interested in removing columns using **dplyr** where the following characteristics are met:

- column values are identical
- column names are identical

## Data

I'm working with data set corresponding to the extract:

```
data("mtcars")
dta <- cbind(mtcars, mtcars[,1:4], mtcars[,1:2], mtcars[,4:6])
```

## Task

Using **dplyr** I would like to come back to the original *mtcars* data by removal of duplicate columns. *In real world, the original mtcars is not available to me, i.e. I'm not able to get a list of names of columns that should be in the data.*

### Attempt 1

I would like to do something on those lines:

```
require(dplyr); require(magrittr)
dta %<>%
  select(matches(unique(names(dta))))
```

Naturally this won't work:

> Error: is.string(match) is not TRUE

In addition the code does not incorporate checking for existence of duplicate values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be we can try

```
dta %<>% 
    setNames(.,make.unique(names(.))) %<>%
    select(-matches("\\.\\d+"))
identical(dta, mtcars)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the helpful input. This solves the problem of unique names. I'm wondering whether it would be possible to incorporate a way of checking whether the values are identical. My thinking is that if the values across identically named columns are different I should leave both columns.

Comment: @Konrad With `data.frame`, `data.table`, `tbl_df` etc, duplicate column names are not the desirable characteristic.  If it is a `matrix`, it won't have an issue.  Otherwise, for selecting columns by names, it is always going to be a problem.  Even if you have duplicate column names in the original dataset, I would convert it to unique names so that it won't create an issue in the future.

Comment: Taken on board. The original data set is produced externally. It makes me wonder, whether it would be wise to try an alternative approach and disregard names issue and drop the columns with repeated values. Is there a way to write `select` command so from three columns with identical values only the first one is kept?

Comment: @Konrad I am not too sure about that in the `dplyr`  syntax, but it is possible with `base R` using `?duplicated`